# Data Deletion Issue in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a school project using Spring Boot, and I'm facing an issue where data is being unexpectedly deleted from the properties and property_details tables in my PostgreSQL database. I have checked the code and configuration but couldn't find the root cause.

Despite my best efforts, I'm unable to identify why the data is getting deleted. I have examined the application's log files, which show the SQL statements for table creation and alterations, but no explicit DELETE queries.

The database connection is configured in the application.yml file with hibernate.ddl-auto: none. I have ensured that there are no DELETE, TRUNCATE, or other data deletion statements executed during application startup or shutdown. There are no explicit table creations or modifications in my code or scripts. The database logs do not show any DELETE or TRUNCATE statements executed.

As I'm new to Spring Boot and database interactions, I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to investigate this issue further. Thank you in advance for any assistance and guidance you can provide. Below are the relevant code snippets

```
port: 8080
  
spring:
  # Database configuration
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST:localhost}:${DB_PORT:5432}/${DB_NAME:postgres}
    username: ${DB_USER:postgres}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD:admin}
  # JPA configuration  
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      # Avoid issue with JPA case insensitive
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
    # This should no longer be needed with Hibernate 6
    # database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG10Dialect
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
    # PotGIS configuration
    properties:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("property")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class PropertyController {
    @Autowired
    private PropertyService service;
    
    @Autowired
    private PropertyDetailsService propertyDetailsService;

    @GetMapping("{name}")
    public String getProperties(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Welcome to SpringBoot Project!!! " + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("{lat}/{lon}/{distanceKm}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCityNear(
            @PathVariable double lat,
            @PathVariable double lon,
            @PathVariable double distanceKm) {
        List<Property> properties = service.findAround(lat, lon, distanceKm);

        if (properties.isEmpty()) {
            // If no properties found, return a custom message with 404 status code
            String message = "Properties are not available in your area.";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new CustomMessage(message));
        } else {
            // If properties found, return the properties in the response with 200 status code
            return ResponseEntity.ok(properties);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("names")
    public String getPropertyNames() {
        List<Property> properties = service.getAllProperties();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Property property : properties) {
            sb.append("City Name: ").append(property.getCityName());
            sb.append(", Price: ").append(property.getPrice());
            sb.append(", Property Name: ").append(property.getPropertyName());
            sb.append(", Property Type: ").append(property.getPropertyType());
            sb.append(", Area: ").append(property.getArea()).append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{propertyId}/details")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPropertyDetails(@PathVariable Long propertyId) {
        PropertyDetails propertyDetails = propertyDetailsService.getPropertyDetailsById(propertyId);

        if (propertyDetails != null) {
            // If property details found, return them in the response with 200 status code
            return ResponseEntity.ok(propertyDetails);
        } else {
            // If property details not found, return a custom message with 404 status code
            String message = "Property details not found for property ID: " + propertyId;
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new CustomMessage(message));
        }
    }

    // Custom message class
    private static class CustomMessage {
        private String message;

        public CustomMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity(name = "properties")
public class Property {

    @Id
    @Column(name="property_id")
    private long id;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "property", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PropertyDetails propertyDetails;
 
    
    @Column(name="city_name")
    private String cityName;
    
    @Column(name="property_location", columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")
    private Point propertyLocation; 
    
    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;   

    @Column(name = "property_name")
    private String propertyName;

    @Column(name = "property_type")
    private String propertyType;

    @Column(name = "area")
    private double area;
    
    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }
    
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public String getPropertyType() {
        return propertyType;
    }

    public void setPropertyType(String propertyType) {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(double area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Property [id=" + id + ", cityName=" + cityName + ", propertyLocation=" + propertyLocation
                + ", price=" + price + ", propertyName=" + propertyName + ", propertyType=" + propertyType
                + ", area=" + area + "]";
    }

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "property_details")
public class PropertyDetails {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "property_details_id")

    private Long propertyDetailsId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "property_id")
    private Property property;

    @Column(name = "images")
    private String images;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "property_type")
    private String propertyType;

    @Column(name = "property_size")
    private Integer propertySize;

    @Column(name = "contact_info")
    private String contactInfo;

    @Column(name = "floor_plan")
    private String floorPlan;

    @Column(name = "property_features")
    private String propertyFeatures;

    @Column(name = "build_year")
    private Integer buildYear;
    
    @Column(name = "nearby_facilities")
    private String nearbyFacilities;

    public Long getPropertyDetailsId() {
        return propertyDetailsId;
    }

    public void setPropertyDetailsId(Long propertyDetailsId) {
        this.propertyDetailsId = propertyDetailsId;
    }

    public String getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPropertyType() {
        return propertyType;
    }

    public void setPropertyType(String propertyType) {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
    }

    public Integer getPropertySize() {
        return propertySize;
    }

    public void setPropertySize(Integer propertySize) {
        this.propertySize = propertySize;
    }

    public String getContactInfo() {
        return contactInfo;
    }

    public void setContactInfo(String contactInfo) {
        this.contactInfo = contactInfo;
    }

    public String getFloorPlan() {
        return floorPlan;
    }

    public void setFloorPlan(String floorPlan) {
        this.floorPlan = floorPlan;
    }

    public String getPropertyFeatures() {
        return propertyFeatures;
    }

    public void setPropertyFeatures(String propertyFeatures) {
        this.propertyFeatures = propertyFeatures;
    }

    public Integer getBuildYear() {
        return buildYear;
    }

    public void setPropertyBuildDate(Integer buildYear) {
        this.buildYear = buildYear;
    }

    public String getNearbyFacilities() {
        return nearbyFacilities;
    }

    public void setNearbyFacilities(String nearbyFacilities) {
        this.nearbyFacilities = nearbyFacilities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PropertyDetails [propertyDetailsId=" + propertyDetailsId + ", images=" + images + ", description=" + description
                + ", price=" + price + ", address=" + address + ", propertyType=" + propertyType + ", propertySize=" + propertySize
                + ", contactInfo=" + contactInfo + ", floorPlan=" + floorPlan + ", propertyFeatures=" + propertyFeatures
                + ", buildYear=" + buildYear + ", nearbyFacilities=" + nearbyFacilities + "]";
    }

    
}
```

```java
package com.hin.spatial.postgis.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.hin.spatial.postgis.model.PropertyDetails;

public interface PropertyDetailsService {
    
    PropertyDetails getPropertyDetailsById(Long propertyDetailsId);
    List<PropertyDetails> getAllPropertyDetails();
    PropertyDetails savePropertyDetails(PropertyDetails propertyDetails);
    void deletePropertyDetails(Long propertyDetailsId);

}
```

```java
package com.hin.spatial.postgis.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.hin.spatial.postgis.model.PropertyDetails;
import com.hin.spatial.postgis.repo.PropertyDetailsRepository;

@Service
public class PropertyDetailsServiceImpl implements PropertyDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyDetailsRepository propertyDetailsRepository;

    @Override
    public PropertyDetails getPropertyDetailsById(Long propertyDetailsId) {
        return propertyDetailsRepository.findByPropertyDetailsId(propertyDetailsId);

    }

    @Override
    public List<PropertyDetails> getAllPropertyDetails() {
        return propertyDetailsRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public PropertyDetails savePropertyDetails(PropertyDetails propertyDetails) {      
        return propertyDetailsRepository.save(propertyDetails);
    }

    @Override
    public void deletePropertyDetails(Long propertyDetailsId) {
        
        propertyDetailsRepository.deleteById(propertyDetailsId);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.hin.spatial.postgis.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.hin.spatial.postgis.model.Property;
import com.hin.spatial.postgis.repo.PropertyRepository;

import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel;


@Service
//@Slf4j
public class PropertyService {
    @Autowired
    private PropertyRepository repo;    
    
    private GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
    
    public List<Property> findAround(double lat, double lon, double distanceKm){
//      log.info("Looking for Properties around ({},{}) withing {} Km", lat, lon, distanceKm);
        Point p = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lon, lat));        
        List<Property> pros=repo.findNearWithinDistance(p, distanceKm * 1000);
        System.out.println(pros);
        return pros;
        
    }
    public List<Property> getAllProperties() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface PropertyDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PropertyDetails, Long> {
    PropertyDetails findByPropertyDetailsId(Long propertyDetailsId);
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface PropertyRepository  extends JpaRepository<Property, Long>{

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM properties WHERE ST_DistanceSphere(property_location,:p) < :distanceM",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Property> findNearWithinDistance(Point p, double distanceM);
    
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.hin.spatial</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgis</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>postgis</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot integrated with PostGIS</description>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <jackson.jts.version>2.14</jackson.jts.version>
        <jts.version>1.19.0</jts.version>
        <hibernate.version>6.1.3.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphhopper.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.jts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
            <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.locationfinderapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>locationFinder</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>gcr.io/distroless/java:17</image>
                    </from> <!-- or ":8" -->
                    <to>
                        <image>ghcr.io/nouhouari/spring-boot-postgis</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you plz share your pom file as well.

Comment: I have added pom.xml file as well

Comment: I feel I commented/answered the same question yesterday? Anyway enable debug logging (debug: true in your yaml), startup and see what is happening. Check your path for `hibernate.properties`/`hibernate.cfg.xml`/`persistence.xml` which can and will override properties. Make sure you don't have system or environment variables set that influence this. If you have a `schema.sql` check what it does, the same for a `data.sql`. Share a link to your project on github as the snippets here don't give the full picture.